# QT Is there another way to load images without QTNetworkManager?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on the tile_map plugin of Mapviz. The Tile-Plugin loads images (tiles) using a WebRequest from the servers. As I have downloaded already all the images on my hard drive, I'm trying to remove the WebRequest from the code - so it wont use the network access. The plugin is using the QTNetworkAccessManager. What would be the recommended way/methods to replace the NetworkAccessManager?

Greets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details) is the recommended way (and only way that I know of that is supported by Qt) of accessing resources over HTTP. The API is made the way it is for performance reasons, it will hide implementation details, conserve power and allow for the kind of optimizations that are available in HTTP without you having to do anything special.

If you have all the files locally, I would simply wrap the code that uses QNAM so that it looks for and prefers the local copy (possibly while keeping a copy in memory too, for performance). So it would cache like this:

`memory-copy > disk-copy > network-copy`

TIP: I found [this PDF](http://devdays.kdab.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/speeding-up-your-Qt-app-with-new-QtNetwork-features.pdf) to be really good for explaining how to use QNAM in the best way.